# Multiply 2 large numbers and store it in a long variable, but over flow occurs

Tags: c++

Why, when I multiply 2 large numbers and store it in a long variable, overflow occurs and I must put `(long)` at the right hand side?

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    long x=100000*90000; //why i should code long x=(long)100000*90000;
    cout<<x;
  }
```

> ```
> /* main.cpp:18:14: warning: integer overflow in expression
> [-Woverflow]  long x=100000*90000;
>         ~~~~~~^~~~~~ 410065408 */
> ```

Comment: You are overflowing by multiplying 2 integers. The math is done by int * int.

Comment: both `100000` and `90000` are integer literals of type `int`. Multiplying them overlflows `int` no matter to what you assign the result

Comment: Instead of a cast, you could use an `L` suffix on one or both numbers.

Comment: Related: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)

Answer (score 2):

The key here is the priority (actually it is called operator precedence) of operations. Since the priority of a multiplication is higher than the priority of an assignment, the type of the result (of sub-expression) is first evaluated for the product operation. Since both operands are *int*, the result will be *int* and the number doesn't fit to integer. At this stage of expression evaluation it doesn't matter what the type will be later, when the assignment will be evaluated.

When you use (long)100000 or 100000L you explicitly tell the compiler that one of the operands is of type *long* and so must be the result's type. In this particular case type cast *(long)* has larger priority than multiplication, so it casts the type first.

Actually, on some platforms you may even need to convert to *long long* type in order to fit: (long long)100000 or 100000LL.

Another widespread example of this trap is:

```
 double d = 3/2;
```

which ends up with d=1.0 by the same reasons.

Comment: the cast has a higher "priority" than the `*` so it's applied first

Comment: “Integer” is a mathematical term for numbers without fractions; the types `char`, `short`, `int`, `unsigned`, `long`, and others are all integer types. So saying “the result will be integer” is not informative. The operands are `int` values, so the result would be an `int`.

Comment: ".... 100000L you explicitly tell the compiler that one of the operands is of type long" is true when `100000` is within the `long` range, but not all constants.  With `12345678901L`, the type is `long long` when `long` is 32-bit.

Comment: @MohamedKhaled, so what's in your way to accept the answer, then(by pressing the Accept button at the left)?  )

Comment: @EricPostpischil, well, this is right and fixed, thank you. At the same time, this is a kind of jargon. We used to name int as integer in daily conversations and people are fine with this. As all of us fine with the term *priority* for operands which is not a part of a language standard, since it uses other ways to describe operator precedence. We use some simplifications when we explain things to people who is new to language. Anyway, corrected. Thank you.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, another good catch. I just answered to the question as it was, so since Mohamed Khaled said that *long* works for him, I kept my answer simple. Anyway, you are correct. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Why, when I multiply 2 large numbers and store it in a long variable, overflow occurs and I must put `(long)` at the right hand side?

More precisely, you multiply 2 large numbers, *then* overflow occurs, after which you store the product in a `long` variable. The overflow occurs in the middle of this process, not at the end.
With a bit more detail: you multiply 2 values of type `int`, overflow what `int` can store, *then* convert to `long` (so you can store the product in a `long` variable). There is nothing hinting that you want the result to be a `long` value until evaluation reaches the assignment, so the earlier operation (multiplication) proceeds with what it has (`int` values).

By casting the first operand to `long`, you change the order in which things happen. The operands are converted to `long`, then you multiply and no overflow occurs because the product fits in a `long`. After that, assigning a value to a variable of the same type has no special consideration.

**Note 1:** Your cast converts (just) the first operand to `long`. The second operand is converted to `long` because the multiplication operator expects both factors to have the same type. Well, there is a more precise, technical explanation involving the rules for [integral conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions), but "expects the same type" gives a good feel for a majority of the cases. Just remember that it is a simplification, not a hard rule.

**Note 2:** Using `100000L` would give the same result as using `(long)100000` with less typing.

Comment: Just a side note on your first note, it sounds like the first argument of the multiplication is the one that matters, but  it’s also true no matter which of the arguments get casted, to be “more careful” about overflowing

Comment: @sagi Hmm... I tried editing something like that into the note, but I didn't like the results. For now, I'll leave that either as something to think about (since "expects both factors to have the same type" does not favor one operator over the other), or as something to get from reading your comment.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to others' suggestion to use `L`, `long` may be 32-bit and overflow still happens with `100000L * 90000`.

Using `L` does not certainly help enough.

Consider `long long`.

```
long long x = 100000LL * 90000;
```

---

**Cast vs. suffix**

Consider this view [if the C-style cast to `long` works, then so will `L`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69020561/multiply-2-large-numbers-and-store-it-in-a-long-variable-but-over-flow-occurs/69021320?noredirect=1#comment121986015_69021320).

Cast has a weakness.  A cast forces the result to `long` - this may narrow the result.  Suffix `L` will not narrow the constant, only potentially widen it.

```
(long) 9000000000  // With 32-bit `long`, this is a (long) 410065408
9000000000L        // With 32-bit `long`, this is a (long long) 9000000000
```

The first likely and unfortunately quiets a useful warning about the narrowing.